# I cannot change a global variable

Tags: c, function, global-variables

as my first C program, I am trying to do a LMC. The problem is that I want to modify a global variable (`input_temp`), but every print I do outputs me a `0`. I saw no post that could help me. How can I fix that ?

```
char input_temp[3];

void INPOUT(){
    /*If the argument is '01', copies the value from the "in box" onto the accumulator.
    If the argument is '02', copies the value from the accumulator to the "out box".*/
    switch(ADD){
        case 1:
            scanf("%3d", input_temp);
            printf("input_temp");
            printf(input_temp);
            printf(">\n");
            ACC = atoi(input_temp);
            printf("ACC: %d\n", ACC);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("%3d\n", ACC);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: on instruction %d: instruction '9' can only be used with arguments '01' and '02'", PC);
            exit(IO_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
input_temp>
ACC: 0
```

Comment: Please read the [printf man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and search for basic examples. `printf(input_temp);` You need to give a format string.

Comment: `scanf("%3d", input_temp);` `%d` requires an `int *` variable not a `char *`. `atoi(input_temp)` don't need to convert if you are reading into an int with `%d`.

Comment: Is your input to `scanf` successful ? Are you trying to provide integer or char ? Type mismatch with `input_temp` and format specifier

Comment: @kaylum : a string without format specifiers is still a valid format string for `printf`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Not in this case since it is currently not a valid string. I meant to say the format specifier is needed to print if it is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

change you scanf to

```
  scanf("%3s", input_temp);
```

and input_temp to

```
  char input_temp[4];
```

one for NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
    scanf("%3s", input_temp);
    printf("input_temp");
    printf("%s", input_temp);
    printf(">\n");
    char * var = input_temp;
    printf("ACC: %s\n", var);
```

This should do the job!